# Why javascript counted wrong?

Tags: javascript, multiplication, calc

Why javascript counted wrong?

```
console.log(3*9.7)    // =29.099999999999998?
console.log(3*97/10) // = 29.1
```

Comment: This already has an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 0):

this is how Javascript's floating point arithmetic works. If you would like to know more how to avoid this I would recommend checking out this link. [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)